dnf install #packagename always tries previously failed installations before installing package
I am new to Linux/Fedora.
Previously I failed to install a package simply because the package's name was wrong.
Now, whenever I install anything else with sudo dnf install #packagename, the software first tries to install this misnamed package. Additionally, it always tries to download a miniscule amount of data and install it as WineHQ.
Why does dnf install #packagename install anything else other than #packagename and its dependcies?
How do I stop this from happening?
Console Output:

Thanks

The error indicates that the host dl.winehq.org was inaccessible.  I can reach the host from where I am. Is this still an issue for you?  If not, then it was just a transient error and we can close this question.

I can not reach the host. But I presume this is an issue beyond my control. The great fire wall isnt easily traversed.

So the solution would include finding an alternate host to pull the package from, or a VPN setup of some form.

I have a VPN, but a VPN is not always reliable. the party isnt sleeping at the wheel ,thanks for the answer though. Also ppl have been arrrested by the police before for using a VPN, its a thin line.
